# Can hotlinking of internet content be considered generally legal?

Tags: copyright, internet, photography

After the [Perfect 10 vs. Amazon case](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_10,_Inc._v._Amazon.com,_Inc.) can the practice of [hotlinking (inline linking)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_linking) of content in general and images in particular, be considered legally valid in general?

To make it a bit provocative: suppose, hypothetically, I'm a competitor of an ecommerce site selling many of the same products. On my product pages, instead of using my own photographs, I simply inline link to the photographs used in (and presumably owned by) my competitor's site. Can they legally prevent me from doing this? I'm not stealing their images, not  copying them: simply providing the web address where they're stored so a browser (or app) can access and display them.

Of course, business wise, the competitor can (periodically) update their systems such that the addresses I use display nonsensical photos and have their own website use the updated addresses and show valid images, but this question is just about the legal side of it.

Comment: The 9th has a limited jurisdiction (West US); nothing it says is certain to be a general rule for the internet.

Comment: The question of which this is seen as a duplicate is about iframing. Not hotlinking per se.